# How can I update a value in a YAML file?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have this YAML file:

```
id: "bundle-1"
version: "1"
apiVersion: "1"
description: "Desc"
jcasc:
  - "jenkins.yaml"
plugins:
  - "plugins.yaml"
```

I want to modify the file by increasing the version number by 1.

I tried this code:

```
import sys
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import yaml

file_name = 'bundle.yaml'

yaml.preserve_quotes = True
with open(file_name) as yml_file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(yml_file)

value = int(data['version'])

print(type(value))

value += 1

str(value)

print(type(value))

data['version'] = str(value)

data = str(data)


print(value)

with open(file_name, 'w') as yaml_file:
    yaml_file.write( yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout))
```

But I get this output, without double quotes and ordered differently:

```
id: bundle-1
apiVersion: 1
description: Desc
jcasc:
  - jenkins.yaml
plugins:
  - plugins.yaml
version: 1
```

Comment: I don't see an issue here. YAML is deliberately designed in a way that the same data can be represented in multiple different ways, and generally with YAML tools you aren't expected to be able to control the exact output - only what it means. The important part is whether the resulting YAML file actually works for its next purpose.

Comment: A more important problem I see is that the `version` is not incremented. You will have to debug your code to figure out why. I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you are doing.

Comment: I wonder if the `data = str(data)` step might be unnecessary/causing a problem.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That seems likely.

Answer (score 0):

> But I get this output, without double quotes and ordered differently:

Since this is an object, the order of the keys don't matter. Also, yaml doesn't require quotes around strings. It looks like the library you are using omits them.

This is not a problem since the YAML is valid.

A more important problem I see is that the `version` is not incremented. You will have to debug your code to figure out why. I don't see anything obviously wrong with what you are doing.

On a side note, this line looks strange to me:

```
yaml_file.write( yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout))
```

I don't know what `yaml` library you are using, but I doubt that `yaml.dump()` returns anything. You probably need to do this instead:

````
yaml.dump(data, yaml_file)
```

You should refer to the documentation for this library to learn the correct usage of the `dump()` function.
````

Comment: Explaining why there isn't a meaningful question, isn't answering a question. If you agree with me on the point (and it seems that you are saying the same thing as in my comment), please instead vote to close the question.

Comment: @CSchofx Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @CSchofx If your answer is accurate and correct, I will upvote it myself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see where you were coming from. I initially started drafting a comment and then decided to post it as an answer. I'm not yet convinced this question should be closed, though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do delete the line `import yaml`, instantiate a `YAML()` instance, and set the `preserve_quotes` attribute
on it. And then use the 'load() `and 'dump()` methods.
There is never, ever use for `safe_load()` and `safe_dump()`.

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
id: "bundle-1"
version: "1"
apiVersion: "1"
description: "Desc"
jcasc:
  - "jenkins.yaml"
plugins:
  - "plugins.yaml"
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
data['version'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString(int(data['version']) + 1)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
id: "bundle-1"
version: "2"
apiVersion: "1"
description: "Desc"
jcasc:
  - "jenkins.yaml"
plugins:
  - "plugins.yaml"
```

Please note that I do not import `yaml` and neither should you.

This code:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as yaml_file:
     yaml_file.write( yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout))
```

will write `None` to the file you open, as that is what `yaml.dump()` returns. Instead do:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path('bundle.yaml')
yaml.dump(data, path)   # with yaml being a YAML instance
```

Comment: @Anton, the above code gives me this error 

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../bundle.py", line 14, in <module>
    data['version'] = ruamel.yaml.scalarstring.DoubleQuotedScalarString(int(data['version']) + 1)
TypeError: string indices must be integers
e5627653@MLV68JML7L provision-mm % ```

Comment: @lankan That output below "which gives" comes from running that exact code. And that line is not line 14 in my example, so you did something wrong, copy-pasting the code. Start with a fresh copy and test after every change, make sure to print `data` before the assignment to `data['version']` to make sure it is a dict.